# Error al crear imagen con Yocto para Xilinx ZCU104

Tags: linux, xilinx, yocto

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con Yocto y mi primer objetivo es la creación de una imagen simple que corra sobre un kit de evaluación de Xilinx (ZCU104). Supongo que con la configuración y las capas adecuadas debería funcionar porque no tuve problemas para crear una imagen qemux86-64 para simular con qemu. Hasta el momento se realizan en torno al 75% de las tareas antes de que aparezcan los siguientes errores:

```
ERROR: u-boot-xlnx-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed ERROR: u-boot-xlnx-v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/.../poky/build/tmp/work/zcu104_zynqmp-poky-linux/u-boot-xlnx/v2020.01-xilinx-v2020.2+gitAUTOINC+bb4660c33a-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1585588' failed with exit code 1:  

//Cientos de líneas que parecen comandos de compilación, no mensajes de error ni direcciones en las que buscar logs con errores. 

ERROR: Task (/.../poky/build/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-xlnx_2020.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1' NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2214 tasks of which 2199 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.   Summary: 1 task failed:   /.../poky/build/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-xlnx_2020.2.bb:do_compile Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Los pasos que he seguido han sido los siguientes:

1. Clonar Poky y checkout de la rama `gatesgarth`
2. Clonar `meta-xilinx`, `meta-xalinx-tools` y `meta-openembedded` (meta-xilinx-tools depende de meta-python y meta-oe), checkout en todas las layers de la rama gatesgarth para asegurar compatibilidad.
3. `bitbake-layers add-layers` de las layers del punto anterior y comprobación en `conf/bblayers.conf`.
4. La variable MACHINE de `conf/local.conf` modificada para mi evalboad: `MACHINE ??= "zcu104-zynqmp"`.
5. En el README de meta-xilinx-tools aparece un ejemplo de las dependencias que hay que incluir para otra tarjeta (zcu102) en el archivo meta-xilinx-tools/blob/master/recipes-bsp/bootbin/machine-xilinx-zynqmp.inc. Todas las dependecias que se mencionan en ese README están contenidas por defecto en ese archivo excepto una que hay que modificar ligeramente:

```
BIF_PARTITION_IMAGE[atf]="${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/arm-trusted-firmware-${TUNE_PKGARCH}.elf" instead of BIF_PARTITION_IMAGE[atf]="${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/arm-trusted-firmware.elf"
```

Lo he probado con y sin esta modificación con el mismo resultado, por lo que el error debe estar en otro lugar.

6. bitbake core-image-minimal que termina en el error mencionado arriba.

Recogiendo información de aquí y allá he llegado hasta este punto, pero no sé por dónde seguir.

¿Ha conseguido alguien usar Yocto para crear imágenes que corran sobre un evalboard de Xilinx como el mío o similar? Tal vez salga de ojo qué paso me he saltado o qué he configurado mal, pero desde mi desconocimiento tengo la sensación de que más o menos debería estar listo para generar imágenes.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.